# Meteor onCreateUser method error

Tags: javascript, meteor, accounts

I want an email to be sent to a user after they register for the site. However, I keep getting the error:

```
I20150729-22:44:52.253(-4)? Exception while invoking method 'entryCreateUser' Error: Match error: Expected string, got undefined in field [0]
I20150729-22:44:52.254(-4)?     at checkSubtree (packages/check/match.js:159:1)
I20150729-22:44:52.255(-4)?     at packages/check/match.js:206:1
I20150729-22:44:52.255(-4)?     at Array.forEach (native)
I20150729-22:44:52.255(-4)?     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:105:1)
I20150729-22:44:52.255(-4)?     at checkSubtree (packages/check/match.js:204:1)
I20150729-22:44:52.255(-4)?     at check (packages/check/match.js:32:1)
I20150729-22:44:52.255(-4)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.sendEmail (app/server/methods/email.js:3:5)
I20150729-22:44:52.255(-4)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1617:1)
I20150729-22:44:52.255(-4)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1530:1
I20150729-22:44:52.255(-4)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20150729-22:44:52.256(-4)? Sanitized and reported to the client as: Match failed [400]
```

Here is my onCreateUser method:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {

        var userEmail = user.email
        var emailSubject = "Welcome to Company!";
        var emailBody = "SUP";

         Meteor.call('sendEmail',
                        userEmail,
                        '',
                        '',
                        emailSubject,
                        emailBody
                      );
    });
```

Can someone help?

Thanks!!

Comment: From the error I think your email passed to create user, is undefined, it will be helpful if you can show how you're creating user. Any packages or custom code?

Comment: Hi - I just realized that onCreateUser is to actually create a user. I want to send a specific email to a user after their account is created.. any ideas? Thx!

Comment: Specifically, i want a post-create hook.

Comment: you should use the same 'onCreateUser' method to send a mail to the user when created

Comment: and one more thing is you should return `user` from that method. `return user` at the end of the createuser method

Comment: What's your `entryCreateUser` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at the [collection-hooks package](https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks) to trigger code right after the user document has been created. It's also useful for modifying the user document itself before it is stored. Of course it can be used for any collection, not just users.